# Tryning to convert JAR to EXE

Tags: java, user-interface, launch4j

I'm Trying to convert JAR to EXE using Launch4J, but when ever I launch my .exe it says "A JNI error has occurred" and gives me his error in launche4J.

```
**Executing: D:\01kitrand\Escape From Tarkov Kit Randomizer.exe
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: GUI has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 60.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)**
```

Comment: As the error states, you need to upgrade your Java Runtime to at least 60.

Comment: What version of Java runtime are you building for?